# How to set up spatie/laravel-feed content type to xml?

Tags: laravel, rss, laravel-8, content-type

I use Laravel v8 with spatie/laravel-feed v4 with this codes:

**routes/web.php**

```php
Route::get('feed', '\App\Models\Blog\Post@getFeedItems')->name("feeds.main");
```

**config/feed.php**

```php
<?php

return [
    'feeds' => [
        'main' => [
            /*
             * Here you can specify which class and method will return
             * the items that should appear in the feed. For example:
             * [App\Model::class, 'getAllFeedItems']
             *
             * You can also pass an argument to that method.  Note that their key must be the name of the parameter:             *
             * [App\Model::class, 'getAllFeedItems', 'parameterName' => 'argument']
             */
            'items' => ['App\Models\Blog\Post', 'getFeedItems'],

            /*
             * The feed will be available on this url.
             */
            'url' => '/feed',

            'title' => 'News',
            'description' => 'The description of the feed.',
            'language' => 'hu-HU',

            /*
             * The image to display for the feed.  For Atom feeds, this is displayed as
             * a banner/logo; for RSS and JSON feeds, it's displayed as an icon.
             * An empty value omits the image attribute from the feed.
             */
            'image' => '',

            /*
             * The format of the feed.  Acceptable values are 'rss', 'atom', or 'json'.
             */
            'format' => 'atom',

            /*
             * The view that will render the feed.
             */
            'view' => 'feed::atom',

            /*
             * The mime type to be used in the <link> tag.  Set to an empty string to automatically
             * determine the correct value.
             */
            'type' => 'application/atom+xml',

            /*
             * The content type for the feed response.  Set to an empty string to automatically
             * determine the correct value.
             */
            'contentType' => '',
        ],
    ],
];
```

The result in webpage's HTML code:

```html
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://mydomain.test/feed" title="News">
```

But if I open the link in browser the result contains JSON code.

How can I set up correctly / force the `application/atom+xml` content type?

Comment: update `'contentType' => 'application/xml'`

Comment: @RamanathMandal thanks the suggestion, but not help

Comment: @netdjw.i have checked its returning xml.try clearing view or changing browser

Comment: @JohnLobo I tried it, but not helped, still I get JSON format

Comment: @netdjw.strange i  have tried in laravel 8 its working

Comment: @JohnLobo Yes :) this question is beeing because it's strange :)

Comment: @netdjw. still you have issue ?

Comment: @JohnLobo yes, I have

Comment: @netdjw before you got json only because of \App\Models\Blog\Post@getFeedItems this because it return json .you can verify by creating separate project .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234333/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-netdjw).

Answer (score 0):

The error is in route

```
Route::get('feed', '\App\Models\Blog\Post@getFeedItems')->name("feeds.main");
```

So it should be

```
Route::get('/feed',FeedController::class)->name("feeds.main");
```

or

```
Route::feeds();
```

Comment: I tried both suggestions, but none worked.

Comment: @netdjw. it works .try clearing route cache php artisan route:clear ,php artisan view:clear and php artisan config:clear

Comment: remove Route::get('feed', '\App\Models\Blog\Post@getFeedItems')->name("feeds.main"); this route